# CSS to fit image to container when image is smaller than the container

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code which works fine to fit an image to its container while keeping the image size ratio.

```
img { /* ASSUMING THE IMAGE IS WIDER THAN 150PX OR HIGHER THAN 100PX */
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
div.mydiv1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

However, if the image is both shorter and narrower than the container, it does stretch to fit (keeping size ratio). Is there a way to do this?

Here a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/many_tentacles/uz3e7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using an `img` tag you might find it easier to achieve your desired functionality by using the css attribute `background: url('path/to/img') no-repeat ...` and `background-size: contain`

So for example in the css

```
div.mydiv3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color:red;
    background: url("http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/careers2-ad-header-so-crop.png") no-repeat red;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="mydiv3"></div>
```

I updated your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uz3e7/4/

Comment: I like this answer. I would not even have thought of this. You sir get an up vote.

Comment: I have come across this method before but ultimately this is going to be used alongside a third-party plugin so might not work without a bit of tinkering with the plugin. You get my vote though since it does indeed answer the question!

Answer (score 3):

The closest I think you are going to get is to set the either the height or width (which ever one you want to math it's container) to 100% and the other to auto. Adding an overflow: hidden; to the container will keep the image from overlapping anything else. 
That is to say:

```
img {
    max-height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T34nw/) to see what I mean. I also agree with cpreid that what you seem to be asking isn't possible. Not without changing the size/shape of the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/uz3e7/2/

```
img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need some javascript to do it,

Take a look at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uz3e7/10/)

**Javascript**

```
$("img").each(function(){    
    var real_width = $(this).width();
    var real_height = $(this).height();
    var parentwidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var parentheight = $(this).parent().height();

    var ratioParent = parentwidth / parentheight;
    var ratio = real_width / real_height;    
    var max_width = $(this).css("max-width");
    if (ratioParent < ratio) {        
        $(this).css({width: "100%", height: 'auto'});
    }else{
        $(this).css({width: "auto", height: '100%'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `object-fit: cover` on the `<img>` element:

```
img { object-fit: cover; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply set the width to 100% ?

Also: It is impossible for some img to scale up and fit the container, edge-to-edge, while insuring it's ratio is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand your question but try using min-width and min-height to give minimum size to your image.